# how to read json response in asp.net with c# (Reseller Club Domain Check Availability API Integration)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api

I am using [this](http://manage.directi.com/kb/answer/764) API and from this API I am getting following output.

```
{"apple.com":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"dotin"},"microsoft.com":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"dotin"},"asdfghq.in":{"status":"available","classkey":"dotin"}}
```

Note : here this output is depend on customer's input.

and Now here can you suggest me that how can I get this output in table format like[image]

Comment: What do you mean "table format"? Rendering a list of objects (repeater? MVC helper? DataGrid?) has nothing to do with how that list is generated (parsing the Json string). How you render the data matters. For example, you could bind directly to the parsed data in MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I for example convert to `DataTable`.

```
private string jsonObject = JSON_String.Replace("{", "[{").Replace("}", "}]");

public JsonExample()
        {
            JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(jsonObject);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("St.No");
            dt.Columns.Add("DomainName");
            dt.Columns.Add("status");
            dt.Columns.Add("classkey");

            foreach (JProperty item in jArray[0])
            {
                var stNo= 0;
                var jArray2 = JArray.Parse(item.Value.ToString());

                foreach (var item2 in jArray2)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(++stNo,  item.Name, item2["status"], item2["classkey"]);
                    Console.WriteLine($" St. No: {stNo} DomainName: {item.Name} Status: {item2["status"]}  classkey {item2["classkey"]} ");
                }
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.NET (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). If you have never used JSON.NET, you can look at code samples in the link to get a feel: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm.

Considering the functionality in JSON.NET, the following code may not be the most elegant way but it gets your job done.

```
private class DomainProp
{
    public string status;
    public string classkey;
}
```

Assuming you have the class above:

```
string sJSON =@"{'apple.com':'status':'regthroughothers','classkey':'dotin'},
    'microsoft.com':{'status':'regthroughothers','classkey':'dotin'},
    'asdfghq.in':{'status':'available','classkey':'dotin'}}";

Dictionary<string, DomainProp> dicDomainProp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, DomainProp>>(sJSON);
// get into table format
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn("S.No."),
    new DataColumn("Domain Name"),
    new DataColumn("Status"),
    new DataColumn("Classkey") });

int i = 0;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DomainProp> pair in dicDomainProp)
    dt.Rows.Add(++i, pair.Key, pair.Value.status, pair.Value.classkey);
```

Comment: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: @. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: Could not cast or convert from System.String to _Default+DomainProp.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the data is easy using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm):

```
var input = "{ \"apple.com\":{ \"status\":\"regthroughothers\",\"classkey\":\"dotin\"},\"microsoft.com\":{ \"status\":\"regthroughothers\",\"classkey\":\"dotin\"},\"asdfghq.in\":{ \"status\":\"available\",\"classkey\":\"dotin\"} }";

dynamic data = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(input);
```

This will return a list of objects whose `Name` property is the domain name, and their `Value` property contains `status` and `classkey` properties contains the contents of the respective fields.

By declaring the result as `dynamic` we can use the dictionary keys as if they were properties of their object.

Rendering this as a table depends on the framework you are using. For example, one simple way to do this with ASP.NET MVC this is:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>Domain Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Class Key</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{

            int i = 1;
            foreach (var it in data)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@(i++)</td>
                    <td>@it.Name</td>
                    <td>@it.Value.status</td>
                    <td>@it.Value.classkey</td>
                </tr>
                }
            }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The result is :

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S.No.</th>
      <th>Domain Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Class Key</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>apple.com</td>
      <td>regthroughothers</td>
      <td>dotin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>microsoft.com</td>
      <td>regthroughothers</td>
      <td>dotin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>asdfghq.in</td>
      <td>available</td>
      <td>dotin</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

1 first convert your json into object form

Copy/pest your json object into json2sharp and copy/pest ModelObject into your code

> http://json2csharp.com/

2 Deserialize your json into modelobject

```
ModelObject object = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ModelObject >(result);
```

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to understand your answer. because If i follow first step it will create class for me but my output will be different everytime.

Comment: @ImranLuhur there's nothing wrong with the input. The `JavaScriptSerializer` though is deprecated and *very* old. Even Web API uses Json.NET

Comment: With a dynamic json result, this solution will not be suitable.